# docker wordpress:latest and wordpress:cli auto install wordpress how to

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose

I want to setup a wordpress container,install wordpress with default servername, username and password. Later I want to use wordpress:cli to change the default language, add some plugins, etc.

The goal is to test a Wordpress plugin in different scenarioes.

But I'm stuck with the basic setup:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # WordPress Service
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  # MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  #WP-CLI Service
  wp-cli:
    image: wordpress:cli
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    entrypoint: wp
    command: >
      sh -c '
      wp core install --url="http://localhost:8088" --title="Example Site" --admin_user="admin" --admin_password="admin_password" --admin_email="info@example.com" --skip-email;
      '

volumes:
  wordpress_data:
  db_data:
```

I expected to end up with a finished installed wp.

I'm getting this error:
`wp-cli-1     | Error: The site you have requested is not installed. wp-cli-1     | Run` wp core install `to create database tables. wp-cli-1 exited with code 1`

my http://localhost:8000/wp-admin/install.php is up and running and I can successfully install everything manually.

I think this might have to do with the wp-config.php

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_USER', 'example username') );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD', 'example password') );

but I don't understand how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing preventing your setup from running is this line

```yaml
entrypoint: wp
```

in `wp-cli` service configuration. Just remove it.

In logs you'll get info about successfull install but also a new warning:

```bash
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2024/02. 
Is its parent directory writable by the server?
Success: WordPress installed successfully.
```

It's about write permissions. To fix the warning add this line to `wp-cli` service:

```yaml
user: xfs
```

I also remember that later during some `wp-cli` operations I had issuses with `wp-cli` not being able to create some cache directory. Adding single environment variable solved this.

```yaml
environment:
    WP_CLI_CACHE_DIR: /var/www/html/.wp-cli/cache/
```